# How to loop through a get curl output and put it into a JSON file then a .CSV file?

Tags: json, csv, for-loop, curl

I am running a little bash script that passes in some credentials, and then loops on the specified pages and takes that information and places it into a .json file called output. I want to then convert that .json file into a .csv file so I can read it a bit more clearer. Is there anyway I can do this correctly?

Using any site to convert a .json file to .csv provides me an error because it looks like the output creates multiple JSON objects, due to the scope of the GET request iterating over multiple pages.

```
TOKEN="value123"

curl -k >> output.json \
--header "Auth-detials: $TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
https://someapi.com/api/details?page%5Bnumber%5D=[1-10]
```

Comment: So you have a JSON that you want to convert to CSV, huh. You can convert it easily with  `mlr` or `jq`, all depends on the content though

Comment: BTW, your URL is subject to glob expansion, you should quote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can save from getting JSON, CSV file by curl and jq.

`Auth` and Token. it depends on REST-API service.

I can't test in my hand without specific URL.

So I focused JSON data to convert CSV by curl.

source URL

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

JSON data

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }
...
```

Target CSV - some items removed - but you can add it

```
1,Leanne Graham,Bret,Gwenborough,92998-3874,hildegard.org
2,Ervin Howell,Antonette,Wisokyburgh,90566-7771,anastasia.net
3,Clementine Bauch,Samantha,McKenziehaven,59590-4157,ramiro.info
4,Patricia Lebsack,Karianne,South Elvis,53919-4257,kale.biz
5,Chelsey Dietrich,Kamren,Roscoeview,33263,demarco.info
6,Mrs. Dennis Schulist,Leopoldo_Corkery,South Christy,23505-1337,ola.org
7,Kurtis Weissnat,Elwyn.Skiles,Howemouth,58804-1099,elvis.io
8,Nicholas Runolfsdottir V,Maxime_Nienow,Aliyaview,45169,jacynthe.com
9,Glenna Reichert,Delphine,Bartholomebury,76495-3109,conrad.com
10,Clementina DuBuque,Moriah.Stanton,Lebsackbury,31428-2261,ambrose.net
```

Using this command in terminal

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | jq -r '.[] | { id: .id, name: .name, username: .username, city: .address.city, zipcode: .address.zipcode, website: .website } | join(",")'
```

[image]

if add this, save CSV file.

```
> data.csv
```

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | jq -r '.[] | { id: .id, name: .name, username: .username, city: .address.city, zipcode: .address.zipcode, website: .website } | join(",")' > data.csv
```

```
cat data.csv
```

[image]

Key steps

#1 Remove `[` and `]`

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | jq '.[]'
```

#2 Filter and change data

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | jq -r '.[] | { id: .id, name: .name }'
```

result

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Ervin Howell"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Clementine Bauch"
}
...
```

#3 to convert CSV

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users | jq -r '.[] | { id: .id, name: .name, username: .username } | join(",")'
```

result

```
1,Leanne Graham,Bret
2,Ervin Howell,Antonette
3,Clementine Bauch,Samantha
...
```

Reference

[How to convert JSON to CSV using Linux / Unix shell](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-using-linux-unix-shell/)

Comment: That makes sense, but what if by default the api only gives me 10 users per page, that is why i had the [1-10] so that it would scale to all pages that are applicable. Thoughts on that?

Comment: It depends on design of API service limit. 10 is small number generally 100 or more is fine.
Can you share `someapi.com` real name URL?