# Puppeteer / Excel VBA: how to scrape table data from website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer, puppeteer

I have used Excel VBA & IE to access website financial data tables for 15 years, but this is now obsolete. So I am trying to use Puppeteer on a Raspberry Pi  to dump the website data to disk which Excel VBA on Win10 can then pick up and process. Getting the page data is easy enough, but how do I convert the page data, retrieved via page.content(), into a useful format? I'm very new to Puppeteer HTML etc..

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk');
 await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 1000})
 wait page.goto (portfolio URL);
 const fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFileSync('ms.txt', await page.content());
```

The relevant data in ms.txt looks like this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_PM_MainContent_gv_Portfolio" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody><tr class="gridHeader">
        <th class="gridHeaderText" scope="col"><img class="GridArrow" src="../../includes/images/arrow_asc_small.gif" align="middle" style="border-width:0px;"> <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$SecurityName')">Holding</a></th><th class="gridHeaderText" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$StarRatingM255')">Morningstar<br>Rating</a></th><th class="gridHeaderNumeric" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$ClosePrice')">Current<br>Price</a></th><th class="gridHeaderText" scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th class="gridHeaderNumeric" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$ReturnD1')">Price<br>Change<br>%</a></th><th class="gridHeaderNumeric" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$Weight')">Weight<br>%</a></th><th class="gridHeaderNumeric" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$PM_MainContent$gv_Portfolio','Sort$ClosePriceDate')">Date</a></th>
```

And the table elements:

```
</tr><tr class="gridItem">
<td class="msDataText" style="width:375px;"><a href="/uk/stockquicktake/default.aspx?id=0P0000M5OM">Burford Capital Ltd</a></td><td class="msDataText" style="width:95px;"><span>Not Rated</span></td><td title="09/12/2022" class="msDataNumeric" style="width:75px;">7.1300</td><td class="msDataText" style="width:20px;">GBP</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="width:60px;">0.56</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="width:70px;">0.0000</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="width:80px;">09/12/2022</td>
</tr><tr class="gridAlternateItem">
<td class="msDataText" style="width:375px;"><a href="/uk/stockquicktake/default.aspx?id=0P00007YPZ">Centrica PLC</a></td><td class="msDataText" style="width:95px;"><img src="../../includes/images/5stars.gif" style="border-width:0px;"></td><td title="09/12/2022" class="msDataNumeric" style="width:75px;">0.9224</td><td class="msDataText" style="width:20px;">GBP</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="color:Red;width:60px;">-0.30</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="width:70px;">0.0000</td><td class="msDataNumeric" style="width:80px;">09/12/2022</td>
</tr><tr class="gridItem">
```

I have a slight preference for deciphering the web data in Puppeteer, but doing it in VBA is also fine if it is simpler. I do want it to be simple and reliable, and to work for another 15 years so I want to avoid unusual 3rd party add-ins. Using Selenium seems complicated and over the top for my purposes, although I am not wedded to Puppeteer if there is a simpler method.

Comment: The domain morningstar.co.uk/uk does not contain any table tag. But if you have a html file from which you want to read data, then you can simply include it as an object under VBA with `Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")` (declare it beforehand with `Dim doc as Object`. The html file can be loaded with xhr and brought into the doc object with `doc.body.innerHTML = xhr.responseText`). Then you can simply access the desired data with the known DOM methods like `getElementsByTagName()`, `getElementByID()`, etc. The part should look something like in your macro for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree puppeteer is simple and reliable.

### This is demo page

[image]

### Find selector

if you click F12 in Chrome, you can see the HTML source code.

And select `Element` tab and click this icon
[image]

Then hove your mouse on the table,
You can see the match  and class name, id string and xpath of tag.

[image]

I will scrap `Interim Result` and `Income Statement` table by selector of `querySelectorAll`

First table

```
<div id="FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott" class="box financialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott">
    <table class="right years2">
        <caption class="sectionHeader">Interim Results </caption>
        <colgroup>
...
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="colDataPoint" id="MsStockReportFiprhDp" scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col" class="number" id="MsStockReportFiprhY1">30/06/2021</th>
                <th scope="col" class="number" id="MsStockReportFiprhY2">30/06/2022</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th headers="MsStockReportFiprhDp" scope="row">Turnover</th>
                <td class="number" headers="MsStockReportFiprhY1">64.23</td>
                <td class="number" headers="MsStockReportFiprhY2">65.41</td>
            </tr>
...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

It's tree of tag is

```
<div id="FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott">
  <table>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>64.23</td>
```

The tree of tag level and id can find 64.23 data

```
[id='FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott'] table tbody tr td
```

If call

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id='FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott'] table tbody tr td")
```

Will return all of table data.
That is main Idea.

### This is demo code

From this code, call getData() function with two parameter
first is URL, it will what is looking for Web page
second is URL, it will what is looking for table by ID.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

async function getData(url, table_id) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);   // #1 from remote Web server
        // #2 From local file open option
        // const contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('D:/temp/answer204/data-sub/MS-Portfolio.html', 'utf8');
        // await page.setContent(contentHtml);

        titles = await page.evaluate((table_id) => {
            const selector = `[id=\'${table_id}\'] table tbody tr td`
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector),
                title => title.innerText.trim());
        }, table_id);

        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

// url = 'https://tools.morningstar.co.uk/uk/stockreport/default.aspx?tab=10&vw=fs&SecurityToken=0P0000M5OM%5D3%5D0%5DE0WWE%24%24ALL&Id=0P0000M5OM&ClientFund=0&CurrencyId=BAS'
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/MS-Portfolio.html'

let tableId = 'FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott'
getData(url, tableId)
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(tableId);
        console.log(titles);
        tableId = 'FinancialsIncomeStatementSummaryHemscott'
        getData(url,tableId)
            .then((titles) => {
            console.log(tableId);
            console.log(titles);
        })
    })
```

#### For from local file instead remote URL open.

```
        // await page.goto(url);   // #1 from remote Web server
        // #2 From local file open option
        const contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('D:/temp/answer204/data-sub/MS-Portfolio.html', 'utf8');
        await page.setContent(contentHtml);
```

### Running and Result

First result is `Income Statement`
Second table result is `Interim Result`
The order is flipped due to async/await not guarantee is order call
That is why I log the table ID in code.

```
$ node get-data.js
FinancialsInterimPrelimResultsHemscott
[
  '64.23',  '65.41',
  '-20.41', '11.22',
  '-0.13',  '-0.10',
  '0.05',   '0.06'
]
FinancialsIncomeStatementSummaryHemscott
[
  '319.11', '386.44', '326.42', '316.68',
  '-12.76', '-',      '-',      '-',
  '-',      '-',      '-',      '-',
  '-',      '-',      '-',      '-',
  '-',      '-',      '-',      '-',
  '249.18', '305.11', '194.21', '201.72',
  '-59.44', '249.30', '317.58', '180.80',
  '164.78', '-56.43', '249.30', '317.58',
  '180.80', '164.78', '-72.07', '229.46',
  '293.00', '152.37', '164.78', '-113.12',
  '1.20',   '1.50',   '0.82',   '0.75',
  '0.00'
]
```

### Next Steps

You may needs those items

#1 What page's table want to scrap - it is hard question, I recommend [`Scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) in Python.

#2 Add table column and row title - you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757549/data-scrapping-to-get-not-only-h3-tag-name-but-also-the-link-and-picture-that-go/74765739#74765739)

#4 may table convert JSON to CSV format for VBA - it will help in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661457/how-to-loop-through-a-get-curl-output-and-put-it-into-a-json-file-then-a-csv-fi/74663385#74663385)

#5 Needs to save a file with table(or page) name and table data - you needs to investigate or googling.

- Note - how to copy HTML to clipboard then paste your code editor
  [image]

Real Demo with Questioner HTML data.

Code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getData(url,header_class,  row_class) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        titles = await page.evaluate((header_class, row_class) => {
            // table header
            // <tr class="gridHeader">
            // 'Holding\tMorningstar\nRating\tCurrent\nPrice\t \tPrice\nChange\n%\tWeight\n%\tDate'
            const headerSelector = `tr[class=\'${header_class}\']`
            headers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(headerSelector), row => row.innerText.trim());

            // table rows data
            // <tr class="gridItem">
            //   '3i Infrastructure Ord\tNot Rated\t3.2900\tGBP\t-0.30\t0.0000\t14/12/2022',
            const rowSelector = `tr[class=\'${row_class}\']`
            rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(rowSelector), row => row.innerText.trim());

            // add header at the begin from rows data
            rows = headers.concat(rows)
            return rows.map((row) => {
                return row.split('\t');
            });
        }, header_class, row_class);

        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

// modify your target URL
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/MS-Portfolio.html'

getData(url,'gridHeader', 'gridItem')
    .then((rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        console.log(rows.length);
    })
```

Result

```
$ node get-table.js
[
  [
    'Holding',
    'Morningstar\nRating',
    'Current\nPrice',
    ' ',
    'Price\nChange\n%',
    'Weight\n%',
    'Date'
  ],
  [
    '3i Infrastructure Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '3.2900',
    'GBP',
    '-0.30',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'abrdn Asia Pacific Equity I Acc',
    '',
    '3.5291',
    'GBP',
    '0.28',
    '16.6667',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Amati AIM VCT Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '1.2650',
    'GBP',
    '0.00',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [ 'Aviva PLC', '', '4.4740', 'GBP', '0.16', '0.0000', '14/12/2022' ],
  [
    'Baronsmead Second Venture Trust Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.6300',
    'GBP',
    '0.00',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [ 'Basf SE', '', '47.2300', 'EUR', '-0.63', '0.0000', '14/12/2022' ],
  [
    'BH Macro USD Ord',
    '',
    '46.7000',
    'USD',
    '-0.29',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'BlackRock World Mining Trust Ord',
    '',
    '6.8100',
    'GBP',
    '-1.16',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'British American Tobacco PLC',
    '',
    '32.6800',
    'GBP',
    '0.48',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Burford Capital Ltd',
    'Not Rated',
    '7.0400',
    'GBP',
    '-2.43',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Diageo PLC',
    '',
    '37.6450',
    'GBP',
    '0.13',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'E.ON SE',
    'Not Rated',
    '9.2860',
    'EUR',
    '1.38',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Fidelity Special Values Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '2.7200',
    'GBP',
    '-0.55',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Gaming Realms PLC',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.2580',
    'GBP',
    '1.47',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Gold Bullion Securities',
    'Not Rated',
    '167.8900',
    'USD',
    '-0.09',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Haleon PLC',
    'Not Rated',
    '3.2110',
    'GBP',
    '0.60',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Henderson Diversified Income Ord',
    '',
    '0.6820',
    'GBP',
    '-0.87',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Herald Ord',
    '',
    '17.7600',
    'GBP',
    '-0.78',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Hotel Chocolat Group PLC',
    'Not Rated',
    '1.4000',
    'GBP',
    '-1.41',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'HSBC S&P 500 ETF GBP',
    '',
    '32.9555',
    'GBP',
    '-0.67',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Imperial Brands PLC',
    '',
    '20.3400',
    'GBP',
    '0.69',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'IP Group PLC',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.5995',
    'GBP',
    '-1.32',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares $ Treasury Bd 20+y ETF USD Di...',
    '',
    '3.2425',
    'GBP',
    '0.42',
    '16.6667',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares China Large Cap ETF USD Dist GBP',
    '',
    '66.2450',
    'GBP',
    '0.91',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares Core FTSE 100 ETF GBP Dist',
    '',
    '7.3510',
    'GBP',
    '-0.09',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares MSCI Brazil ETF',
    '',
    '26.4700',
    'USD',
    '-0.19',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares MSCI EM ETF USD Dist GBP',
    '',
    '30.4413',
    'GBP',
    '0.80',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'iShares Physical Gold ETC',
    'Not Rated',
    '35.2850',
    'USD',
    '-0.27',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'ITV PLC',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.7668',
    'GBP',
    '0.08',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'JPMorgan Indian Ord',
    '',
    '8.3600',
    'GBP',
    '-0.24',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'MannKind Corp',
    'Not Rated',
    '4.9500',
    'USD',
    '1.15',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Merck & Co Inc',
    '',
    '111.5500',
    'USD',
    '1.16',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Mobeus Income & Growth 4 VCT Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.7650',
    'GBP',
    '0.00',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'National Grid PLC',
    '',
    '10.2750',
    'GBP',
    '1.18',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Pantheon Infrastructure Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.9440',
    'GBP',
    '0.85',
    '16.6667',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'PepsiCo Inc',
    '',
    '183.3600',
    'USD',
    '-0.35',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Picton Property Income Ltd',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.8230',
    'GBP',
    '-0.60',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'RWE AG Class A',
    '',
    '42.7300',
    'EUR',
    '1.05',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Samsung Electronics Co Ltd GDR',
    '',
    '1,163.0000',
    'USD',
    '-0.29',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Schroder UK Mid Cap Ord',
    '',
    '5.4500',
    'GBP',
    '0.18',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Shell PLC',
    '',
    '22.9600',
    'GBP',
    '-0.95',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [ 'SSE PLC', '', '17.2550', 'GBP', '1.00', '0.0000', '14/12/2022' ],
  [
    'Standard Chartered PLC',
    '',
    '6.0660',
    'GBP',
    '-0.23',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'The Income & Growth VCT Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '0.7600',
    'GBP',
    '0.00',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Tritax Big Box Ord',
    'Not Rated',
    '1.5180',
    'GBP',
    '1.81',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'UBS(Lux)FS MSCI EMU GBPH Adis',
    'Not Rated',
    '11.1290',
    'GBP',
    '-0.13',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'United Utilities Group PLC',
    '',
    '10.3650',
    'GBP',
    '0.24',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'VanEck JPM EM LC Bd ETF A USD',
    '',
    '53.7600',
    'USD',
    '-0.18',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Vanguard FTSE 100 UCITS ETF',
    '',
    '32.8900',
    'GBP',
    '-0.09',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Vanguard S&P 500 ETF USD Acc GBP',
    '',
    '60.4600',
    'GBP',
    '-0.67',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Viatris Inc',
    'Not Rated',
    '11.3200',
    'USD',
    '-0.25',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ],
  [
    'Wells Fargo & Co',
    '',
    '42.1800',
    'USD',
    '-1.11',
    '0.0000',
    '14/12/2022'
  ]
]
53
```

#### local HTML server by VS Code extension.

#### #1 Copy HTML file from Chrome's DevTool

1.1 Launch Chrome and enter URL

```
https://tools.morningstar.co.uk/uk/stockreport/default.aspx?tab=10&vw=fs&SecurityToken=0P0000M5OM%5D3%5D0%5DE0WWE%24%24ALL&Id=0P0000M5OM&ClientFund=0&CurrencyId=BAS
```

1.2 Press F-12 key for open DevTool panel

1.3 select that icon for inspect mode
and mouse hove over web page - it will turn whole page mask.

1.4 mouse hove over <html> tag

1.5 right click and go `Copy`/`Copy element` menu then select
[image]

#### #2 Paste HTML into VS code with `index.html` file

[image]

Select `Format Document` (right click on file, pop up menu will shows) then save it.

[image]

Install [`Live Server`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension in VS code.
[image]

Press `Go Live` menu on right/down side in VS code.
[image]

Then Local html server launching
[image]

#### #3 Run your `Web-Scrapping` software(your puppeteer based node.js)

You can debugging and fine tuning the selector.

Comment: Fantastic! Apologies for delay in replying but the site's portfolio function was down. In MS-Portfolio however there is no <div id>. It seems the table is governed by <div class="ms_panel"> then <div>, <table cellspacing ... id="ct100_maincontect" ....>, <tbody>, <tr class="gridItem"> and then several <td class="msDataNumeric" style="...;">123.456</td>. And some of the <td class> have a <a href> with text. I've tried a few things none of which worked. I need to learn all this properly at some point but currently just don't have the time unfortunately!

Comment: @drb01 - can you point out URL which class based <div> tag page? then I can show how to access it.

Comment: Unfortunately you need an account to access this page. But I did a screen dump, does this help? The highlighed <div> line highlights the entire table that I want data from. https://www.dropbox.com/s/slee2dallg1gm1x/MS%20portfolio%20elements.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I got your mail, I send intermediate version but I will send again after return work in tonight.

Comment: @drb01, I updated my answer base on your real HTML, can you confirm it. it is looking for you want?

Comment: Works wonderfully. Incredibly helpful - thank you!

Comment: Thanks you! I am happy to hear your can do it. Enjoy web scrapping.

Comment: A related question, I see you tested on a HTML file I sent you using page.goto('http://127.0.0.1:5500/MS-Portfolio.html'). I am trying something similar using page.goto('d:\\ms-portfolio.html') (Windows) where my-portfolio.html was created using Chrome's Save As function. The page half loads but then ultimately timeouts. Any idea where I am going wrong? I also tried using fs.WriteFileSync('MS-portfolio.html', await page.contect()).

Comment: @drb01, I update my answer with local HTML server steps. I hope to address your problem.

Comment: Any reason to save a file during web-scrapping?

Comment: Can I try you working on specific web site to want to save it?

Comment: It's not that I want to save a website.  I want to test code on a page that requires a lengthy logging in every time. So it is much quicker to save the page to a file (once I have logged in) and then test my nodejs code on that file. It's what you seem to have done with url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/MS-Portfolio.html'; await page.goto(url);

Comment: Which URL for MS-Portfolio.html?

Comment: I tried this 'd:\\MS htmlpage1.html' , where the file was created using your method above using Chrome and Visual Studio IDE. I get the same result, it just timeouts

Comment: My question which URL you test it. It do not matter the content?

Comment: It may be help to specify the directory for live-server.
https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Comment: that's probably where I have gone wrong, I think I have massively over simplified it. I was doing await page.goto('d:\\MS htmlpage1.html') !

Comment: @drb01, I tested it from local file. It works. I update my code. please see `#2 From local file open option` part.

Comment: // await page.goto(url);   // #1 from remote Web server

        // #2 From local file open option

        const contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('D:/temp/answer204/data-sub/MS-Portfolio.html', 'utf8');

        await page.setContent(contentHtml);

Comment: It needs to switch from #1 to #2 option at line 8~11

Comment: It works! I had already tried that but without the 'utf8' which seems to make all the difference. page.setContent(contentHTML) is peculiarly slow, takes about 20 seconds, but it is fine for my purposes. Thanks again!

Comment: Good to know, you got it.  setContent() faster than open(). The open() much slower.